# Validation for non-required field

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have these lines of code to validate for an e-mail address:

```
<h:outputText value="#{labels.eMail}: " />
<p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50" validatorMessage="Please provide a valid e-mail address" value="#{personelView.eMail}">
  <f:validateRegex pattern=".+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+" />
</p:inputText>
```

When I leave the e-mail address field empty and submit the form it gives validation error. Why JSf is doing this? Isn't it supposed to just validate e-mail field with the above code? I even tried adding:

```
required="false"
```

still no good. Does anyone have any idea about this case?

Comment: your inputText value is being validated against your <f:validateRegex pattern=".+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+" /> and if its value not valid you getting the error , so you need to improve your regex... TRY (.+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+)? b.t.w you can also implement a validator class and accept empty string in server side...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

your `inputText` value is being validated against your `<f:validateRegex pattern=".+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+" />` and if its value not valid you getting the error , so you need to improve your regex so it will match your pattern or accept empty string...

So wrapping it with `()` and adding a `?` should do the job

Try

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="(.+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+)?"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to disable it

```
<f:validateRegex pattern=".+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]+" disabled="true"/>
```